# Does completing Mass Effect 2 on insanity difficult give any rewards in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am considering replaying Mass Effect 2 to see how different choices affect Mass Effect 3 and want to know if it is worth playing on insanity.

Comment: I have never seen an answer on this site to date that shows that "difficulty" is a variable that carriers over to ME3. In fact, outside of an achievement, I haven't seen difficulty have an impact on anything period (aside from you know, difficulty).

Comment: Does it set the difficulty of the new game automatically?  That would be about the only residual effect I can think of.

Comment: no, it doesn't.  I imported over my insanity ME2 playthrough and ME3 still defaulted to normal difficulty, I had to turn it up my self.  As for rewards, I have no clue since I got a bunch of stuff on the import so I can't tell if there's anything extra that was due to difficulty.

Comment: I argue the satisfaction of beating ME2 on insanity is in itself worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this extensive article in the wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Save_File_Transfer), no, there aren't any rewards for ME3 by completing ME2 in insanity.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are not currently rewards, but there are several rumors circulating about some being added in future content.